# How do I group a query after ordering it?

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

I'm trying to group a query after i order it, however, in sql (im using DB2) we can't group by after doing order, but if I order after grouping the grouping changes. The reason for this is because its grouped based on multiple attributes not just 1 (i only need to group by 1 attribute but since we are required to match the select statement I have to group by multiple attributes.

I tried doing a virtual table using "with" and tried to order within that but DB2 says that I can only group and not order inside the with attribute

The same goes in the from statement . I tried doing a nested query inside the from attribute which returns the ordered result but DB2 restricts us from ordering inside the from attribute (only grouping is allowed)

So I'm not sure how to do this, how can I group something after ordering it?

Here is a sample table:

pokemon:

id name            age 
 3   pikachu         1  
 2   bulbasure 3 
 1   charazard       2 
 11 pikachu         10

(in pokemon table) 
primary key id, name 
foreign key (name) references pokedex (name) )

pokedex: 

id          status 
pikachu       derp 
charazard     herp 
bulbasure     burp

now what I'm trying to do is list the pokemon table with:
ORDER BY age, name

but after that I want the result to be grouped by their id however Im selecting their id, name, age and status so when grouping I have to match those attributes:

GROUP BY pokedex.id age status.....

so the problem is if I order after the grouping it breaks the grouping of pokedex.id since its grouped by status and other attributes aswell

Just an example, not really building anything related to pokemon :P

Comment: some info about your data/structure will significantly increase the chance of getting useful answer

Comment: Group by is typically done BEFORE an order by.  Can you give us a paste of your current query to help out.

Comment: It makes no sense to order before a group by. GROUP BY does not depend on any inherent order, UNLESS you are using MySQL (tagged), but your description says DB2.  * Mysql is a different story, allowing non-aggregates to be mixed with GROUP BY

Comment: but your restriction on group by is that it must match the same attributes on your select statement so if group by first then order by, the group will break because of common grouping on some of the grouped attributes.

Comment: @Richard aka cybekiwi It can make sense, if, say you have a where to filter data based on the actual order. (Or a limit of some kind).

Comment: I digg your choice of sample table :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see how this might be a problem if you want to ORDER BY variables that you are not wanting to GROUP BY. Not including certain variables in your GROUP BY statement would eliminate those columns FROM the resultant table, and hence you would not be able to order it by them.

In your example, you might want to show how many times a given Pokemon had a certain status, like so:

```
SELECT
   p.name
   ,d.status
   ,count(*) tally
FROM pokemon p
   INNER JOIN pokedex d on p.name=d.id
GROUP BY
   p.name
   ,d.status
```

You couldn't order the above query result by 'age' since you didn't GROUP BY name, status, *and* age.

In this example, I would do:

```
SELECT
   p.age
   ,p.name
   ,d.status
   ,count(*) tally
FROM pokemon p
   INNER JOIN pokedex d on p.name=d.id
GROUP BY
   p.age
   ,p.name
   ,d.status
```

**However**, and to your point, it is not always possible to include in the 'group by' clause those columns you would want to order the data by. So, taking your Pokemon data/tables as my example let me illustrate a general approach that might be helpful:

**1)** First, I would create a table with my custom ordering:

```
SELECT
   *
   ,ROW_NUMBER() as my_order
FROM (
   SELECT
      age
      ,name
   FROM pokemon
   ORDER BY
      age
      ,name
)
```

**2)** Then, I'd join it to the rest of my grouped table, ordering by the custom 'my_order' column I had created for this purpose:

```
SELECT
   a.*
   ,custom.my_order
FROM a   -- I'm calling 'a' your table, after your joins/group bys
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
       name
       ,ROW_NUMBER() as my_order
    FROM (
        SELECT
           age
           ,name
        FROM pokemon
        ORDER BY
           age
           ,name
    ) 
) AS custom ON a.name=custom.name
ORDER BY custom.my_order
```

This is my version of *'grouping after doing an ordering'*, though I don't think about it in those terms - I think of it as a 'custom' ordering.

Comment: how would you create a custom table 1)
if I use with it disallows the use of order by

Comment: are you saying that running a query to produce results in 1) returns with an error? That 'order by' is not allowed to exist in any subselects? What is the exact error that you are shown and what is the code you wrote similar to 1) above?

Comment: in db2 you cant have order by in nested from or virtual tables, it's gives an invalid token error

Comment: @Saad, Not sure which version of DB2 you are running, but at least one version has this functionality: [DB2 for z/OS SQL Reference (7.68 MB)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/dsnsqk19.pdf?noframes=true) -> Then, go to "Examples of subselects", and see Example 12, which contains an 'ORDER BY' clause as part of a subselect.

Comment: @Saad, [the official DB2 forums](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/community/) might be a good bet as well.